# Drawing graphics with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, activex, zedgraph

I need to draw a scatter plot into an activex control I'm building using Visual C++.
I have looked at [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/) but, at first glance, I can't use it as I don't have a frame.

I believe the drawing must be done using the c++ drawing contexts. Is there any Visual C++ API which is able to direct its output to a drawing context object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ZedGraph in terminal-like mode. It's quite easy, you just need to remember about scaling/resizing.

See the example here: http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Use_ZedGraph_to_generate_an_image_from_a_console_application